# What does `::parse()` do on a struct?

Tags: rust

I'm learning rust, and the best way to learn a programming language is obviously reading and understanding other's code. Now I faced this line I am not able to understand even after reading docs, other source files and googling for it :

In [`zoxide`'s](https://github.com/ajeetdsouza/zoxide/blob/main/src/main.rs#L23) main file, there's this line :

```rust
if let Err(e) = App::parse().run() { ... }
```

What does `App::parse()` mean ? App is a structure and not a variable, so I understand why it's not `.parse()`, but why `::parse()` and what does it do ? (I couldn't find its definition in [app's](https://github.com/biluohc/app) source code (nor in [this file)](https://github.com/biluohc/app/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L102))

Comment: For me it looks like this: In `app/_app.rs`, the `clap` macro (from [the `clap` library](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap) is used on `App`, which adds the `parse` function to it. The call to `App::parse()` is then used to trigger the parsing of the command line. (I don't really know Rust so I'm not confident enough in the details of this explanation to create an answer from it.)

Comment: <https://docs.rs/clap/3.0.0-beta.4/clap/trait.Clap.html#method.parse>

Comment: It;s comming from clap_derive: https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/tree/master/clap_derive

Comment: @CherryDT Congrats, you're doing remarkably well for someone who _doesn't really know Rust!_

Comment: @user4815162342 turns out I was wrong though, since the `derive(Clap)` - which I missed - is responsible for it, and not the `clap` macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, both the files you mentioned are not the `App` that zoxide is including. zoxide's `main.rs` file says `use crate::app::{App, Run};`, so it's including `App` from `src/app/mod.rs`, which exports `App` from `src/app/_app.rs`

In that file, we can see the declaration of `App`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clap)]
#[clap(
    bin_name = env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"),
    about,
    author,
    after_help = ENV_HELP,
    global_setting(AppSettings::ColoredHelp),
    global_setting(AppSettings::DisableHelpSubcommand),
    global_setting(AppSettings::DisableVersionForSubcommands),
    global_setting(AppSettings::PropagateVersion),
    version = option_env!("ZOXIDE_VERSION").unwrap_or_default()
)]
pub enum App {
    Add(Add),
    Import(Import),
    Init(Init),
    Query(Query),
    Remove(Remove),
}
```

The key in this case is `#[derive(Clap)]`. If you look at [the clap crate](https://lib.rs/crates/clap) you'll see that it's a crate for parsing command line parameters, and deriving from `Clap` adds a `parse` method to the structure.